Create a dynamic BS list group using jQuery


        var jResult =
            [
                {
                    "JobID": 3,
                    "JobTitle": "DBA",
                    "PostingURL": "https://www.google.com",
                    "PostingText": "Posted at Indeed",
                    "StartDate": "2019-01-14T00:00:00",
                    "EndDate": "2024-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "Active": true
                },
                {
                    "JobID": 1,
                    "JobTitle": "UI Designer",
                    "PostingURL": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                    "PostingText": "Posted at Indeed",
                    "StartDate": "2019-01-14T00:00:00",
                    "EndDate": "2025-02-28T00:00:00",
                    "Active": true
                },
                {
                    "JobID": 4,
                    "JobTitle": "Project Manager",
                    "PostingURL": "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
                    "PostingText": "Posted at Indeed",
                    "StartDate": "2019-03-25T00:00:00",
                    "EndDate": "2024-12-31T00:00:00",
                    "Active": true
                }
            ];
        $.each(jResult, function (index, curr) {
            var title = curr.JobTitle;
            var postingText = curr.PostingText;
            var postingUrl = curr.PostingURL;
            console.log(postingUrl);
            var postDate = curr.StartDate;

            var jLink = '<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></a>';
            var jDiv = '<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between"></div>';
            var hdr = '<h6 class="mb-1"><span>' + title + '</span></h6>';
            var spnSD = '<small><span>' + postDate + '</span></small>';
            var pJob = '<p class="mb-1">' + postingText + '</p>';
            var spnMoreInfo = '<span>Posting URL goes here.</span>';

            $(jDiv).append($(hdr), $(spnSD));
            $(jLink).append($(jDiv), $(pJob), $(spnMoreInfo));
            $("#divLg").append($(jLink));
        });
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="list-group" id="divLg"></div>
</body>
</html>



I am using Ajax to call a web service method to retriev a dataset and trying to display it using BS list group.
I tried different methods of generating individual list items inside a loop, none of which seemed to work. This is the latest attempt.
HTML:
<div class="list-group" id="divLg">
</div>

Ajax success part:
}).done(function (result) {
    if (!result || result.d === "") {
    }
    else {
        jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);

        $.each(jResult, function (index, curr) {
            var title = curr.Title;
            var postingText = curr.PostingText;
            var postDate = curr.StartDate;

            // First attempt, totally off!

            //$('<a>', { class: 'list-group-item list-group-item-action' + (index == 0 ? ' active' : '') })
            //    .append($('<div/>', { class: 'd-flex w-100 justify-content-between' })
            //        .append($('<h6/>', { class: 'mb-1' }, { id: 'spnTitle' + index }).append(document.createTextNode(title)))
            //        .append($('span', { id: 'spnPostStartDate' + index }).append(document.createTextNode(postDate))))
            //    .append($('p', { id: 'pDescr' + index }, { class: 'mb-1' }).append(document.createTextNode(postingText)))
            //    .append($('span').append(document.createTextNode('some text here')))
            //    .appendTo($('#divLg'));

            // Last attempt

            var jLink = '<a id="jLink' + index + '" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action jLink' + index + '" aria-current="true"></a>';
            var jDiv = '<div id="jDiv' + index + '" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between jDiv' + index + '"></div>';
            var hdr = '<h6 class="mb-1 jHdr' + index + '"><span id="spnTitle' + index + '">' + title + '</span></h6>';
            var spnSD = '<small><span id="spnPostStartDate' + index + '" class="jSD' + index + '">' + postDate + '</span></small>';
            var pJob = '<p class="mb-1">' + postingText + '</p>';
            var spnMoreInfo = '<span>Posting URL goes here.</span>';

            $jLink = $(jLink);
            $jDiv = $(jDiv);
            $hdr = $(hdr);
            $spnSD = $(spnSD);
            $pJob = $(pJob);
            $spnMoreInfo = $(spnMoreInfo);

            $('#jDiv' + index).append($(hdr));
            $('#jDiv' + index).append($(spnSD));
            $('#jLink' + index).append($(jDiv));
            $('#jLink' + index).append($(pJob));
            $('#jLink' + index).append($(spnMoreInfo));
            $('#divLg').append($(jLink));
        });
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        });

I am trying to end up with:
<div id="divLg" class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" aria-current="true">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="mb-1">Some Title</h6>
            <small>10/11/2024</small>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-1">Some placeholder content in a paragraph.</p>
        <small>And some small print.</small>
    </a>
    <a ...>
        ...
    </a>
</div>


Aside: $(hdr) should just be $hdr. You don't need to wrap a jQuery object in another jQuery object.

You can't use $('#jDiv' + index) until after you append $jDiv to the DOM.
But since the div you want to append to is in a variable, you can use that instead of searching the DOM.
$jDiv.append($hdr, $spnSD);
$jLink.append($jDiv, $pJob, $spnMoreInfo);
$("#divLg").append($jLink);

.append() can also be given multiple arguments and it will append all of them, instead of calling it repeatedly.

Thank you. After making the recommended changes, when I inspect the dom, I only see divLog div without anything appended to it.

I just realized my very first attempt was right except I missed to enclose 'span' and 'p' tags in <>; a DOH moment!

What to do when someone answers your question

It did not work for me. I made the changes as suggested but just ended up with a blank divLg, None of the other markups were added,

Sorry, I thought the "DOH moment" meant you got it to work.

Can you create a [mre] so I can test the code myself? Replace the AJAX call with a hard-coded jResult value.

I added code snippet. Also, My DOH comment was a reference to Homer Simpson type blunder!

Each time you write $(jDiv) you're creating a new jQuery object, not referring to the same one. Use $jDiv = $("<...>") then $jDiv.append(...)
